# Tate's conjecture for arithmetic schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, chow-groups, l-adic-sheaves

Tate's conjecture is about a map from Chow groups of a smooth projective variety $X$ to the $l$-adic cohomology i.e. $CH^n(X)\rightarrow (H^{2n}(\bar{X}, \mathbb{Q}_l(n)))^G$ where $G$ is the Galois group of the base field. This is expected to be an isomorphism over finite fields but a surjection over number fields. How about the arithmetic schemes where $l$ is invertible? Is this or some version of this supposed to be true? (We might need to replace $l$-adic cohomology with something else like continuous etale cohomology since the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ probably doesn't make sense.)

Over finite fields there is a really nice reformulation by Bruno Kahn, which gives a quasi-isomorphism between complexes related to motivic cohomology and continuous etale cohomology complexes. This breaks down in characteristic zero, was wondering how much of this can be generalized to arithmetic schemes instead. (There are some attempts in the paper but the paper is old and I am not aware of the state of the art.)

Comment: What would $\bar X$ mean in the arithmetic setting?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Yes that is what I am mentioning in above that it doesn't make sense and it probably requires replacing that by a better cohomology. Continuous etale cohomology of roots of unity is one such candidate. The continuous etale cohomology of course will be taken over $X$ instead of $\bar{X}$

Comment: So your question is just about forgetting the "field" part of the Tate conjecture, and finding some substitute for the roles played by a separable closure and Galois group in the statement of the Tate conjecture?

Comment: @Vik78 Right I am wondering whether there is a right formulation of the Tate conjecture in this setting or not. This could look differently than the field version in several ways one is the way you mentioned another one is that we forget about the algebraic closure and find the right cohomology theory instead of the $l$-adic one (Continuous etale is the right one for finite fields). I believe whatever the formulation is it should be compatible with the finite field case since varieties over finite fields are also finite type schemes over integers.

Comment: I was also thinking along the lines of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455116/motivic-complex-on-arithmetic-schemes) there is a small problem with this one that over finite fields it is implied from the Tate but it does not imply Tate so in a way it is weaker than Tate (if true.).

Comment: Interesting question-- unless I am missing something, it's worth noting that any variety over any field is (the base change of) a finite type scheme over the integers (it's quasi-compact and affine-locally we can define it via a finite number of equations whose coefficients we can take to be in a finitely generated field). So you can ask for a reformulation which specializes to the full original statement of the Tate conjecture, right?

Comment: There is actually a reformulation of Tate's conjecture that is closely connected to arithmetic questions (and does not refer to $\bar X$); see for instance §3 of Tate's talk in the [Woods Hole proceedings](https://www.jmilne.org/math/Documents/woodshole.pdf). There, Tate shows (under two assumptions that follow from the standard conjectures) that the Tate conjecture is equivalent to the statement that $\operatorname{rk} \operatorname{CH}^i(X)$ is the order of the pole of $\zeta(X,s)$ at $s = i$. This is a version of the BSD conjecture! He makes this more explicit (beyond finite fields) in §4.

Comment: @Vik78 Yes, the idea is we start from a correct formulation over integers then by taking limit can go over any field. I hope by doing so one might even get a better formulation of Tate (more of a dream at this point). By that I mean a formulation that is not about proving a certain map of groups is surjective but rather it is a quasi-isomorphism of complexes. (Similar to the finite field case). In other words the fact that we only get surjection in char 0 is because we are working with the wrong cohomology theory (my opinion).

Comment: (Technically Tate uses $\operatorname{CH}^i(X)/{\sim_{\text{hom}}}$, but it follows from another set of conjectures by Murre/Beilinson that all equivalences from rational to numerical agree over finite fields, up to torsion. So when counting $\dim(\operatorname{CH}^i(X)/{\sim} \otimes \mathbf Q)$, it shouldn't matter which equivalence $\sim$ you use.)

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn That is correct, the Beilinson conjecture enables us formulate Tate in a much neater way over finite fields, in char 0 we don't have Beilinson but one can hope that there is a better cohomology theory out there ...