# Motivic complex on arithmetic schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, motivic-cohomology

If we believe the finite generation of motivic cohomology for regular arithmetic schemes like $X$ then we can see that (using Quillen-Lichtenbaum)for infinitely many primes $l$ we have an isomorphism of the form: $$H^i(X, \mathbb{Z}(n))\otimes \mathbb{Z}_l\cong \lim_{\stackrel{\longleftarrow}{m}}H^i(X, \tau^{\leq n}R\pi_*\mu_{l^m}^{\otimes n})\cong H^i_{cont \text{ over }m}(X,\tau^{\leq n}R\pi_*\mu_{l^m}^{\otimes n} )$$.

The functor $\pi$ is the forgetful functor from etale sheaves to Zariski sheaves. The last isomorphism holds because by the finite generation assumption the cohomology groups $H^i(X,\tau^{\leq n}R\pi_*\mu_{l^m}^{\otimes n} )$ are finite and hence satisfy the Mittag-Leffler condition.
Is this expected to be true for all invertible $l$? i.e. for all invertible $l$ do we expect a quasi-isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}(n)\otimes \mathbb{Z}_l$ and $Rlim_m \tau^{\leq n}R\pi_*\mu_{l^m}^{\otimes n}$?